# Giving stroke to just one word of a line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I am trying to stroke and make it italic style just one word in a line, like below; but it is very time consuming for me. (I have to copy the whole text, delete all the other word except the one I am trying to change, move it exactly on top the original text, and THEN give stroke)  If change layer style all of them have stroke. Can't I just do it quicker?

[image]

Comment: You can't simply select the word and use the Character Panel to make it Bold? Photoshop employs faux bolds of the font doesn't contain a boldface.

Comment: @Scott It is already bold

Comment: Okay.. I can't think of *any* method to stroke one word of a text string other than what you've posted in your question. It essentially *has* to be a separate object. There's a duplicate question here somewhere (I can't find it) regarding applying a layer style to one word.. same issue.